# Unclear descriptor caller reference evaluation

Tags: python, descriptor

I am using Python descriptors to create complex interfaces on host objects.

I don't get the behaviour I would intuitively expect when I run code such as this:

```
class Accessor(object):
    def __get__(self,inst,instype):
        self._owner = inst
        return self

    def set(self,value):
        self._owner._val = value

    def get(self):
        if hasattr(self._owner,'_val'):
            return self._owner._val
        else: return None


class TestClass(object):
    acc = Accessor()

source = TestClass()
destination = TestClass()

source.acc.set('banana')
destination.acc.set('mango')

destination.acc.set(source.acc.get())
print destination.acc.get()
# Result: mango
```

I would expect in this case for destination.acc.get() to return 'banana', not 'mango'.

However, the intention (to copy _val from 'source' to 'destination') works if the code is refactored like this:

```
val = source.acc.get()
destination.acc.set(val)
print destination.acc.get()
# Result: banana
```

What is is that breaks down the 'client' reference passed through **get** if descriptors are used in a single line versus broken into separate lines? Is there a way to get the behaviour I would intuitively expect?

Many thanks in advance.

K

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation ALMOST works. The problem with it comes up with `destination.acc.set(source.acc.get())`. What happens is that it first looks up `destination.acc`, which will set `_owner` to `destination`, but before it can call `set()`, it has to resolve the parameter, `source.acc.get()`, which will end up setting `acc`'s `_owner` to `source`.

Since `destination.acc` and `source.acc` are the same object (descriptors are stored on the class, not the instance), you're calling `set()` on it after its `_owner` is set to `source`. That means you're setting `source._val`, not `destination._val`.

The way to get the behavior you would intuitively expect is to get rid or your `get()` and `set()` and replace them with `__get__()` and `__set__()`, so that your descriptor can be used for the reason a descriptor is used.

```
class Accessor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner): # you should use the conventional parameter names
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance._val

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance._val = value
```

Then you could rewrite your client code as

```
source = TestClass()
destination = TestClass()

source.acc = 'banana'
destination.acc = 'mango'

destination.acc = source.acc
print destination.acc
```

The point of descriptors is to remove explicit getter and setter calls with implicit ones that look like simple attribute use. If you still want to be using your getters and setters on `Accessor`, then don't make it a descriptor. Do this instead:

```
class Accessor(object):
    def get(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_val'):
            return self._val
        else:
            return None
    def set(self, val):
        self._val = val
```

Then rewrite `TestClass` to look more like this:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.acc = Accessor()
```

After that, your original client code would work.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am working with the PyMEL interface in Autodesk Maya and I have to use this particular pattern for two reasons:
a) I am aware of the __init__-based approach, however instantiating 'interface' objects on __init__ is much, much slower in execution than using descriptors, at least in the Maya interpreter.
b) The .get() / .set() syntax is a PyMEL convention, and I want to stick to it. I realise it is un-descriptor-like.

Comment: Do the existing classes in the PyMEL system use descriptors like that? Or are they using the "init-based" approach? I find it difficult to believe that they maintain that convention if they're using descriptors.

Comment: I have something that will work. I just need to get to a proper keyboard to type it up :). It'll be a couple hours, since I'm getting ready for work right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Jacob. I am not sure how PyMEL is coded internally in this respect, it's a deep package. For the time being I am working from the outside in.

Answer (score 0):

I already said why it's not working in my other post. So, here's a way to use a descriptor while still retaining your `get()` and `set()` methods.

```
class Accessor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        elif not hasattr(instance, '_val'):
            setattr(instance, '_val', Acc())
        return getattr(instance, '_val')

class Acc(object):
    def get(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_val'):
            return self._val
        else:
            return None
    def set(self, val):
        self._val = val

class TestClass(object):
    acc = Accessor()
```

The trick is to move the `get()` and `set()` methods to a new class that is returned instead of returning `self` from the descriptor.